# How to call my post_provision_install hook after CiviCRM installed?

Tags: installation, hooks, aegir

I want to automate the removal of households from CiviCRM, right after it has been installed via Aegir on Drupal 7.

I implemented my [post_provision_install](https://docs.aegirproject.org/extend/altering-behaviours/#running-extra-code-after-a-task) hook, but it runs before the [same hook of Hosting CiviCRM module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/hosting_civicrm/blob/7.x-3.x/drush/install.provision.inc), means before the install of the CiviCRM module.

How can I change the calling order of the `post_provision_install` hooks in this particular case?

Or how can be an `post_hosting_install_task` hook implemented and called?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps do this with a CiviCRM extension rather than a Drupal module so you are sure it is only executed once CiviCRM is installed? Not sure if it is possible in your scenario.

Comment: Thx, will check it. I have Drupal profile, not a module, not sure if it make any difference.

Comment: The solution to automate the removal of households from CiviCRM was to implement the Drupal hook of [hook_modules_installed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_modules_installed/7.x) in the .install file of my Drupal profile.